# Powershell script to read output and if a number is great than send an email

Tags: powershell

I have the current script that is reading a file that has the word Queued: and a number that is followed by a lot of spaces. If the number is greater than 100 it will send me an email

```
$Output = 'D:\alec.data\QueuedJobss.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value

if ($Queued -gt 100 ) {
  $MailArgs = @{
        'To'          = 'alb2112@test.com'
        'From'        = 'netbackup@test.com'
        'Subject'     = 'Over 100 Queued Jobs!'
        'Attachments' = $Output
        'Body'        = 'Check Environment'

        'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.test.com'
       }
     Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
  }
```

I am not very familiar with using these expression cmds to help with it understanding spaces. If there's other solutions to this problem without using expressions please let me know. The output it is reading looks like this -

```
Summary of jobs on ustest01
Queued:                                0
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                          43
Successful:                   25391
Partially Successful:           113
Failed:                         184
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        25731
```

It's receiving the following error, saying it cannot index into a null array. It seems to be having a problem with the expression -

```
    Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:88
+ [int]$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:\s+(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[ <<<< 1].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: Your match is failing which is why the array is null.  Do you get output from your select-string pattern as it is?  I copied your example and tried the command and got the expected return.

Comment: select string is what is coming back as null when I try it.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a wildcard search just in case the file is formatting the whitespace weirdly: `'queued:.*?(\d+)'`

Comment: I changed it to `$Queued = (Select-String -Pattern "Queued:.*?(\d+)" -Path $Output).Matches.Groups[1].Value` and it's still returning null

Comment: Can you confirm your file actually has a number after `Queued:`?

Comment: The file shows the following in that row it's looking at `Queued:                                0` but there's a lot of spaces after Queued: